# List of "best material"/typical questions/outstanding questions/good showcases of our site?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

As @brendansullivan07 suggested in a [comment](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/changes-that-will-occur-when-public-beta-starts-in-the-next-day-or-two), we should perhaps provide a list of the best material our site has thus far. Of course, one could simply order the questions with respect to votes, but maybe there are others that have been lost in the mix.

I suggest we "nominate" questions that accurately portray the scope of our site, which could be used for demonstrative purposes when introducing MESE to a new user.

Note: These questions should not only be good, but should also have high-quality answers.

**Edit (4/7/14):** About two weeks have elapsed since this was last updated, so perhaps there are new questions or answers worth posting/linking to from the past half-month.

Comment: For reference, here are the lists of [highest-voted questions](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and [highest-voted answers](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer)

Comment: I would suggest that we include some questions that have good, accepted answers, as well as some questions that have a variety of answers without any one that's "best".

Answer (score 3):

I propose the following short list:

**Good questions with good, accepted answers**:

- [What is a good handwriting font for mathematics?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-is-a-good-handwriting-font-for-mathematics)
- [Should students be asked to use more than one notation for the derivative in an introductory calculus class?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/562/should-students-be-asked-to-use-more-than-one-notation-for-the-derivative-in-an)
- [What to do when students are not keeping their eyes on their own test?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/588/what-to-do-when-students-are-not-keeping-their-eyes-on-their-own-test)

This has something of administrivia (cheating), something of student understanding (notation), and two explicitly about mathematical issues (while the other is an education idea that is broader but still fits here).

**Good questions with many good answers**:

- [Encouraging class participation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1/encouraging-class-participation)
- [How to teach logical implication?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-to-teach-logical-implication)
- [How can we help students who are very anxious about math?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-can-we-help-students-who-are-very-anxious-about-math)

Again, a little bit of everything, including some good lists of answers that are all good, and some that include links to research.