# Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange featured in the Math Forum's newsletter

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Earlier this week, I was contacted via email by [Richard Tchen](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/math_stat/AMS/richard_tchen.html) from [Math Forum @ Drexel](http://mathforum.org/). He asked me for some example questions to highlight in this week's [newsletter](http://mathforum.org/electronic.newsletter/index.html). I pointed him to the meta question: [List of "best material"/typical questions/outstanding questions/good showcases of our site?](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/list-of-best-material-typical-questions-outstanding-questions-good-showcases-o) Allow me to quote [the item](http://mathforum.org/electronic.newsletter/mf.intnews19.13.html) in full:

> ### Stack Exchange for Mathematics Educators Goes Public
>
> https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/
>
> On Tuesday, a new Q&A site for math teachers went live — and over 400 educators and professors there have already answered hundreds of each others' questions at a clip above 95%.
>
> The Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange has, after a month in development, reached public beta bubbling with questions such as
>
> - How can we help students who are very anxious about math?
> - Should I design my exams to have time-pressure or not?
> - What are the arguments for and against learning multiplication table by heart?
> - How to assign homework when answers are freely available or attainable online?
> - Advantages on repeating question in student's answer
> - What is fairly new theorem one can teach (and prove) to an undergraduate student?
>
> Come freely ask your own question, answer a question, or "vote up" the best answers. Voters get reputation within the community, which plans to periodically hold democratic moderator elections. Especially fruitful questions, helpful answers, and other forms of participation earn badges such as "famous question," "guru," "mortarboard," "booster," and "Strunk & White."
>
> Described as "all about getting answers — no chit-chat," this question-and-answer site requires no cost or registration. For more about the Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange, consult
>
> https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/about
>
> Stack Exchange has for years also operated a popular Q&A for people studying math at any level. Nowadays, the Mathematics Stack Exchange boasts nearly 100,000 members:
>
> https://math.stackexchange.com/

We don't really have a good place to put this on the front page, but we are now:

[image: The Math Forum]

Congratulations to everyone who has helped get this community up and going so quickly!

Comment: That's wonderful! Thanks for sharing the news.