# Publications inspired by Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

(This post is inspired by the MathOverflow Meta question "[Best of MathOverflow, or papers inspired by MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/12357).")

> What publications have mentioned Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange?

This includes the more specific question:

> What questions or answers in Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange led to a publication?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: "[List of “best material”/typical questions/outstanding questions/good showcases of our site?](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/173/77)"

Answer (score 4):

I have published twice on MESE-related posts. One was a textbook chapter about [**MESE 29**](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/29):

> The "water triangle" proportional reasoning task

The publication is:

> Dickman, B. (2018). Creativity in Question and Answer Digital Spaces for Mathematics Education: A Case Study of the Water Triangle for Proportional Reasoning. In *Creativity and Technology in Mathematics Education* (pp. 233-248). Springer. [**Link**](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Benjamin_Dickman/publication/321683932) (no pay wall).

The other publication corresponds to [**MESE 907**](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/907):

> Good problems that uncover difficult points in a theory

(For which I had written an earlier, related answer on MathOverflow: [**MO 60457**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/152300/).)

The publication is:

> Dickman, B. (2017). Enriching divisibility: multiple proofs and generalizations. *The Mathematics Teacher*, 110(6), 416-423. [**Link**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303920376) (no pay wall).

As I understand matters from a pre-print excerpt, this latter publication will make a noteworthy cameo in a chapter from Joel David Hamkins' forthcoming book, which is mentioned [**here**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/introduction-to-proofs-csi-math-505-spring-2017/) as *Proof and the art of mathematical reasoning*.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer as I requested.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mathematics Educators Meta question "[Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange featured in the Math Forum's newsletter](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/77)," Jon Ericson mentions an item mentioning MESE's reaching public beta in March 2014.